# UICollectionView itemises change makes cell flicker on popping child view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have set UICollectionView item size as under with inter item spacing and line spacing.

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowlayout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)self.gridView.collectionViewLayout;
flowlayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake((self.view.frame.size.width/3)-20, (self.view.frame.size.width/3)-20);
flowlayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5.0f;
flowlayout.minimumLineSpacing = 5.0f;
```

When i select a collection view cell, i have pushed new view controller.
After I pop the new view controller. I could see the UICollectionView cell flicker. If i do not set item size and set cell size in story board and do the same sequence, i could not see the flickering issue. Please let me know why the issue happens.